# Add a Property to Each Object in an Array Based on a Value Matching a Property of an Object in a Different Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecma

I have two arrays of objects:

```
const arr1 = [ {key: '12', name: 'john'}, {key: '9', name: 'steve'}, {key: '4', name: 'harry'}, {key: '2', name: 'jane'} ];

const arr2 = [ {key: '12', age: '29', gender: 'm'}, {key: '9', age: '43', gender: 'm'}, {key: '4', age: '19', gender: 'm'}, {key: '2', age: '65', gender: 'f'} ];
```

`arr1` will always contain the same amount of objects as `arr2`, and the `key` property will always be consistent, e.g. in the above example keys `'12', '9', '4', '2'` are present in both arrays.

I'm looking for an efficient way to add the `name` property from each object in `arr1` to the object in `arr2` that has the same value for the key property. The above is a simplified example, in my use-case both arrays could potentially contain 300+ objects.

Expected outcome:

```
arr3 = [ {key: '12', age: '29', gender: 'm', name: 'john'}, {key: '9', age: '43', gender: 'm', name: 'steve'}, {key: '4', age: '19', gender: 'm', name: 'harry'}, {key: '2', age: '65', gender: 'f', name 'jane'} ];
```

I can achieve this with a nested loop that iterates over each object in `arr1` and checks against each object in `arr2`, but wondered if there was a simplified/more efficient way using some of the functions within the more recent versions of ECMAScript (which i'm still learning).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that arr1 and arr2 are always the same length and sorted by their keys you can do this:

```
let arr3=arr2;
for (let i = 0;i<arr1.length;i++){
    arr3[i].name=arr1[i].name;
}
```

my output from doing this:

```
[
  { key: '12', age: '29', gender: 'm', name: 'john' },
  { key: '9', age: '43', gender: 'm', name: 'steve' },
  { key: '4', age: '19', gender: 'm', name: 'harry' },
  { key: '2', age: '65', gender: 'f', name: 'jane' }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps

```js
const arr1 = [ {key: '12', name: 'john'}, {key: '9', name: 'steve'}, {key: '4', name: 'harry'}, {key: '2', name: 'jane'} ];
const arr2 = [ {key: '12', age: '29', gender: 'm'}, {key: '9', age: '43', gender: 'm'}, {key: '4', age: '19', gender: 'm'}, {key: '2', age: '65', gender: 'f'} ];
const concat = arr1.concat(arr2);

var arr3 = Object.values(concat.reduce((acc, {key, ...rest})=>{
    acc[key] = {...(acc[key] || {}), ...{key, ...rest}};
    return acc;
},{}));

console.log(arr3);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```js
const arr1 = [ {key: '12', name: 'john'}, {key: '9', name: 'steve'}, {key: '4', name: 'harry'}, {key: '2', name: 'jane'} ];

const arr2 = [ {key: '12', age: '29', gender: 'm'}, {key: '9', age: '43', gender: 'm'}, {key: '4', age: '19', gender: 'm'}, {key: '2', age: '65', gender: 'f'} ];

arr2.map((elm, index) => {
    elm.name = arr1[index].name;
})

console.log(arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Map to add name property

```js
const arr1 = [ {key: '12', name: 'john'}, {key: '9', name: 'steve'}, {key: '4', name: 'harry'}, {key: '2', name: 'jane'} ];
const arr2 = [ {key: '12', age: '29', gender: 'm'}, {key: '9', age: '43', gender: 'm'}, {key: '4', age: '19', gender: 'm'}, {key: '2', age: '65', gender: 'f'} ];

map=new Map()
arr1.map(o=>map.set(o.key,o))
arr2.forEach(o=>o.name=map.get(o.key).name)
console.log(arr2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr1 = [ {key: '12', name: 'john'}, {key: '9', name: 'steve'}, {key: '4', name: 'harry'}, {key: '2', name: 'jane'} ];

const arr2 = [ {key: '12', age: '29', gender: 'm'}, {key: '9', age: '43', gender: 'm'}, {key: '4', age: '19', gender: 'm'}, {key: '2', age: '65', gender: 'f'} ];

function merge(arr1, arr2) {

    return arr1.reduce((merged, currentObj)=>{
        const index = merged.findIndex(ele =>currentObj.key === ele.key);
        index !== -1 ? merged[index] = {...merged[index], ...currentObj} : merged.push(currentObj);
        return merged
    },arr2)

}

console.log(merge(arr1,arr2))
```